# VK API Python: почему get_url_query() возвращает пустой dict?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, авторизация

Внезапно перестала работать авторизация в VK API, ошибка:

> vk.exceptions.VkAuthError: Authorization error (incorrect password)

Пароль ввожу верный. Покопавшись в исходниках библиотеки понял, что следующий код

```
url_query = parse_qsl(parsed_url.fragment)
```

а именно, `parsed_url.fragment`, возвращает пустой список, из-за чего и возникает исключение. Вопрос в том, почему `fragment` стал возвращать пустую строку? Ведь раньше этого не было.

Есть подозрения, что нужно вводить капчу; тогда вопрос в том, как это сделать в программе?

Заранее спасибо :)

Comment: Не ясно какой либой для работы с api vk работаете и с каким методом api возникает проблема

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать библиотеку [vk-requests](https://github.com/prawn-cake/vk-requests)

Там были исправлены многие ошибки, которые есть в библиотеке vk. Если требуется ввод капчи, то в консоли будет явное сообщение об этом.

Пример использования:

```
>>> import vk_requests

>>> api = vk_requests.create_api(app_id=123, login='User', password='Password')
>>> api.users.get(user_ids=1)
>>> [{'first_name': 'Pavel', 'last_name': 'Durov', 'id': 1}]
```